I cannot use tensorflow and keras
I am trying to use keras to load model. But when I import the keras lib, It got
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tfe: The specified procedure could not be found.

then I try
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

But then I got
ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)

I am using the latest version of tensorflow (2.16.1) and keras (3.3.3)
Any help?

Try uninstall keras and tensorflow incase something has corrupted. And check your in the right environment. I’m assuming it was working if you’re saying you want it to work properly again.

I think keras is integrated into tensorflow. So you do not usually need to install it separately.

@Jordan That is not true anymore, keras 3 is an independent package.

I did uninstall and reinstall tensorflow and keras but it still same

I have successfully executed the code in TensorFlow 2.16.1 .Please refer
gist with the code is attached for your reference.Let me know if you are still
facing the issue
